# jQuery: Start from first value if values are not there

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I have this array in JS

```
var values = ["rgb(236,221,208)","rgb(146,177,182)","rgb(191,209,223)","rgb(187,237,190)"];
```

This array has 4 values, and it is used to add background color to some sections

```
$(".class").each(function(index) {
    var color = values[index];
    $(this).css("background-color", color);
});
```

Suppose if we have 6 rows to add background color, then in that case
`values[4]` and `values[5]` will be undefined

I want to know is there any method in which we can start over the array values once we reach the end? means once we reach the point where `values[4]` is undefined so instead of it we can continue with `values[0]` and so on

`values[0]`, `values[1]`, `values[2]`, `values[3]`, `values[0]`, `values[1]`, `values[2]` ..........

Comment: simply by using % operator you can back to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".class").each(function(index) {
    var color = values[index % values.length] ;
    $(this).css("background-color", color);
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I was not sure to how to word my question on google so was not able to find the solution, now I am stuck can't delete the question